# How to stop thread in ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I start a long operation (usually long query (SELECT) to database).
It might take long time, and I want to add capability to stop this action.
Code looks like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => action.DoLongAction());

public void DoLongAction()
{
    var sql = Tables.Where(el => el.Some == "XXX"); // dynamically constructed LINQ query to database
    var result = db.Query(sql);
}
```

I can't use signals of flags, to stop this thread. Because, long operation isn't in my code, but in database process (sql query about 5 mins).

How can I stop this thread correctly?

UPD1. Not plain SQL, but LINQ (EF4, BLToolkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to abort this Thread manually, then you can use the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class.
For details about how to use it, you can look at this [online resource](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Aborting_Threads).

Please note that usually, using `Thread.Abort();` is not a best practice, except when you are ending your program and wants to terminate all the running threads.

In your case, as you are trying to end a SQL query, you should look at other ways to stop it ([SqlCommand.Cancel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx), [ISession.CancelQuery()](http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/M_NHibernate_ISession_CancelQuery.htm), ...)

Comment: Most importantly, `Thread.Abort` only works in managed code - since the query is waiting in unmanaged code (I/O), the `Abort` will only happen when it finally returns to managed code - by which time, the work is already finished. So yeah, make sure there's a proper way to cancel the work, rather than relying on `Thread.Abort` - that's just a dirty hack.

Comment: from the above explanation it seems that thread pool thread can not be aborted or stopped or cancel......am i right ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. It supports canceling.
But you can only cancel the query in a safe manner, if the database provider supports canceling it. Your code doesn't look like it supports canceling.

Update: After some discussion, the following info also is worth to be put into the answer:
SqlCommand supports cancellation as Guillaume points out, but the database driver used needs to also support it. So best way to do it:
Use SqlCommand or the class derived from it for your DBMS, execute the query and try to cancel it and see whether it is supported. If it is not supported, you will get an exception.
If it is supported, the example for SqlCommand.Cancel will help you to implement the behavior you want.

Comment: But it does not support cancellation from within a database query. It supports cancellation in the sense that you can inject cancellation checks into your code and act apropriately.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am saying with the rest of my answer :-)

Comment: How can it help? It supports cancellin via flag 'CancellationPending'. If I execute long SQL query, how can I check this flag?

Comment: Your main problem is, that your database provider doesn't seem to support cancellation or async processing. Having said that, the only way to stop the execution of the query seems to be to kill the thread it is running in. You can't do that with ThreadPool, see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/6632f5f9-b650-4f16-9e8a-1a37de4970e0. You would need to use the normal Thread class and do all the work yourself.

Comment: If it can help, I can use Entity Framework 4 or BLToolkit. Does they support cancellation or async processing?

Comment: I don't know BLToolkit and EF4 is not used, when you want to execute a statement directly from code. SqlCommand supports cancellation as Guillaume points out, but the database driver used needs to also support it. So best way to do it: Use SqlCommand or a class derived from it for your DBMS, execute the query and try to cancel it and see whether it is supported. If it is not supported, you will get an exception. If it is supported, the example for SqlCommand.Cancel will help you to implement the behavior you want.

Comment: Actually, I'm using LINQ with these SQL queries (not LINQ2SQL), so I'll try to call Thread.Abort. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Thread.Abort is a bad idea. If your provider doesn't support cancellation change provider. If you can't change it... well you are screwed Thread.Abort will raise funny bugs.

Comment: I use EF4 and BLToolkit sometimes. They both supports LINQ in queries. Queries are constructed dynamically. So I can't change my provider. What funny bugs will raise Thread.Abort?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted in my second comment.

Comment: Whoever voted my answer down: Please be so kind to explain why, so I can improve it.

Comment: About Thread.Abort bugs, read notes at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx

Comment: @Guillaume Not only is `Thread.Abort` a bad idea that's bound to cause a bunch of issues (many are fixed by now), but it most likely won't work at all, since it can only abort when the thread is in managed code - which waiting for an I/O callback isn't. So it will only abort *after* the work is done (or failed). So yeah, `Thread.Abort` is no substitute for proper cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Cancel a SQL command, have a look at [SqlCommand.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a timeout value for the SQLCommand. aka, cancel after x seconds if not finished.

Comment: This doesn't help. User wants to get query results or can change own mind and execute other query/task.

Comment: Like someone else said, you may need to use a manageable thread instead of a pool thread. Pool threads are really meant for short lived threads where the cost of creating and destroying a thread isn't worth the work being done. Also, if your connection doesn't support canceling, you're kind of SoL. If you need to cancel a query, then use a DB that supports canceling.